# How to connect to JIRA via Delphi 7?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7, jira

I have a project in JIRA and I have a link to site where I can log in. I want to write a program which let me log in my project site. Is it possible to do in Borland Delphi 7? And if yes, what do I need?

Comment: JIRA the issue tracker? What DB is behind it?

Comment: I mean, I want to connect with that site where I can log in, but via program.

Comment: I think you'll need to be a bit clearer about what you want to do. Maybe take some time and re-work the question so that it conveys your precise intent.

Comment: I edit my question. Is it cleat now?

Comment: Not yet. Once you've logged in, then what?

Comment: Then I want to manipulate with data - view, change, delete, etc. And download it into file (some kind of progress report).

Comment: I think the best way would be to use the JIRA REST API: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Version+2+Tutorial

Comment: So I see it is possible. Thank you @Stefan Glienke

Answer (score 1):

JIRA seems to have a REST API interface, as show in the [official documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/), so you could use [Simple REST Client for Delphi](http://jamiei.com/blog/2013/01/simple-rest-client-for-delphi/) or [Delphi REST Client API](https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/delphi-rest-client-api) to access the rest API from Delphi .